# The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, compiler-errors

i've added a simple *Cshtml* there's nothing in it but when i run the project i get this error and i know there's sth wrong with this file ***bin\roslyn\csc.exe"***

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The file or
> directory is corrupted and unreadable
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The file or directory is corrupted and
> unreadable]
>
> [ExternalException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command
> being executed was "c:\users\mostafa\documents\visual studio
> 2017\Projects\InstagramAutomationPosts\Instagram_Automation_Posts\bin\roslyn\csc.exe"
> /shared /keepalive:"900" /noconfig  /fullpaths
> @"C:\Users\Mostafa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
> Files\vs\a17df867\580bcfa2\mauhk4p3.cmdline".]

My *view*

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Try deleting all files from C:\Users\Mostafa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: @PSK didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding the project solved the issue for me

Comment: I did a clean and a rebuild that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i know it's not correct way to answer but what i did was (and might help someone in future),i made another project and copied everything there  and it got fixed